# build singularity recipe with docker ENTRYPOINT/CMD equivalent functionality

Tags: docker, containers, hpc, recipe

I have a dockerfile which ends

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh"]
CMD ["runscript.sh"]
```

I can run docker with an argument (a shell script) that overrides "runscript.sh" (if i wish). Note: the shell scripts are provided by a `--bind` mount

I am translating my Dockerfile to a Singularity recipe. From my understanding i can replicate this ENTRYPOINT/CMD functionality using the "%startscript" label. I am trying:

```
%startscript
exec "$@"
```

then run an instance of the container using

```
singularity instance start --bind /hostpath:/containerpath model.sif instancename script.sh
```

When i do this i get the message:

```
/.singularity.d/startscript: 4: exec: script.sh: not found
```

I know i am doing this all wrong, but cant seem to work out what.

Note: if i replace `exec "$@"` with `./script.sh` then the script is executed but i am limited to having a script with this name. I want the flexibility to pass any named script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

```
%runscript
```

and not

```
%startscript
```

Then you can pass an argument to run command which will be used in place of the default value in the recipe,

```
singularity exec image argument
```

eg. in the recipe file

```
 %runscript
./runscript.sh
```

then use either

```
singularity exec image.sif
```

or

```
singularity exec image.sif newscript.sh
```

depending on whether you want to run the default container script or the "newscript"

Answer (score 0):

In your original Dockerfile:

1. Remove the `ENTRYPOINT`
2. Make sure the `CMD` includes some sort of path, like `CMD ["./runscript.sh"]`
3. Make sure the first line of the script is a "shebang" line, `#!/bin/sh`
4. On the host system, make sure the script is executable, `chmod +x runscript.sh`, and check that change into source control

This is the same set of steps you'd need to do to be able to run `./runscript.sh` on the host system, without Docker, and the same rules apply.

In the script you show, you're just running `exec "$@"`, presumably as an entrypoint script being passed the `CMD` as arguments.  Your original Dockerfile prepended whatever `CMD` it was given with `sh` (the `ENTRYPOINT` value), but this wrapper doesn't, and that's why you're getting different behavior.

In general I wouldn't encourage splitting out the name of a language interpreter into `ENTRYPOINT`.  I prefer a pattern of `CMD` being a complete command, which is compatible with the sort of entrypoint wrapper script you show.  There's also a pattern of `ENTRYPOINT` being a complete command and `CMD` its arguments (Kubernetes calls these options `command:` and `args:`).  What you have here is kind of a half way, though: if you override `CMD` then you must repeat the program name, but you can only actually run programs that are implemented as shell scripts.

Comment: Thanks David. Maybe my question got lost or maybe i dont understand your reply. I have no problem building or running Docker. I am interested in getting similar results using Singularity under the %startscript label